# Hangman program : To display guesses entered by the user

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on a hangman project and I need a little help.
I want to display all the guesses entered by the user on the right side of  the terminal window in bluej. I want to store it in an array and constantly display it on the right side after every clearScreen() method. Here is my code. Please try it out.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Hangman
{
    String word,clue;
    int option;
    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
    private void clearScreen()
    {
      System.out.print('\u000C');
    }
    public void Hang1()
    {
        p.println("      _______   ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public void Hang2()
    {
        p.println("      _______ ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      ( )");
        p.println("     |       ");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public void Hang3()
    {
        p.println("      _______ ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      ( )");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public void Hang4()
    {
        p.println("      _______ ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      ( )");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      /");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public void Hang5()
    {
        p.println("      _______ ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      ( )");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      / \\");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public void Hang6()
    {
        p.println("      _______ ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      ( )");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      /|");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      / \\");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public void Hang7()
    {
        p.println("      _______ ");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      ( )");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      /|\\");
        p.println("     |       |");
        p.println("     |      / \\");
        p.println("_____|_____ ");
    }
    public String[] Sports()
    {
        option = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clue = "He is an Argentine footballer who plays for La Liga club FC Barcelona and is the captain of the Argentina national team, playing mainly as a forward.";
                word = "L I O N E L | M E S S I";
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                clue = "First person to score 200 in ODIs";
                word = "S A C H I N | T E N D U L K A R";
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                clue = "It is a South Asian team sport.";
                word = "K A B A D D I";
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                clue = "It is a two-player board game";
                word = "C H E S S";
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                clue = "It is a team sport in which two teams of six players are separated by a net.";
                word = "V O L L E Y B A L L";
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                clue = "Known as 'The wall'";
                word = "R A H U L | D R A V I D";
            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {
                clue = "World Table Tennis Champion";
                word = "Z H A N G | J I K E";
            }
            break;
            case 7:
            {
                clue = "A famous sport";
                word = "F O O T B A L L";
            }
            break;
            case 8:
            {
                clue = "Played on a hard board divided by a net";
                word = "T A B L E | T E N N I S";
            }
            break;
            case 9:
            {
                clue = "Grandmaster of chess";
                word = "V I S H W A N A T A N | A N A N D";
            }
            break;
        }
        return new String[] {word,clue};
    }
    public String[] Movies()
    {
        option = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clue = "Movie in which Daniel Radcliffe has acted";
                word = "T H E | W O M A N | I N | B L A C K";
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                clue = "It is a 2012 Indian satirical comedy film that satires organized religion directed by Umesh Shukla";
                word = "O H | M Y | G O D";
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                clue = "Schwarzenegger plays the role of a cyborg assassin sent back in time from the year 2029 to 1984 to kill Sarah Connor";
                word = "T H E | T E R M I N A T O R";
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                clue = "It is a movie about 2 kids who become sspies";
                word = "S P Y | K I D S";
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                clue = "This film stars Jason Statham as Frank Martin, a driver for hire – a mercenary transporter who will deliver anything, anywhere – no questions asked – for the right price";
                word = "T H E | T R A N S P O R T E R";
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                clue = "This film tells the story of Jamal Malik, a young man from the Juhu slums of Mumbai who appears on the Indian version of Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?";
                word = "S L U M D O G | M I L L I O N A R E";
            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {
                clue = "Set during the Sierra Leone Civil War in 1996–2001, the film shows a country torn apart by the struggle between government soldiers and rebel forces";
                word = "B L O O D | D I A M O N D";
            }
            break;
            case 7:
            {
                clue = "This film stars Macaulay Culkin as Kevin McCallister, an eight-year-old boy, who is mistakenly left behind when his family flies to Paris for their Christmas vacation";
                word = "H O M E | A L O N E";
            }
            break;
            case 8:
            {
                clue = "This film follows Dominic Toretto, Brian O'Conner and Mia Toretto as they plan a heist to steal $100 million from corrupt businessman Hernan Reyes";
                word = "F A S T | F I V E";
            }
            break;
            case 9:
            {
                clue = "This film consists of many superheroes";
                word = "T H E | A V E N G E R S";
            }
            break;
        }
        return new String[] {word,clue};        
    }
    public String[] Computers()
    {
        option = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clue = "The brain of the computer";
                word = "C E N T R A L | P R O C E S S I N G | U N I T";
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                clue = "Stores a real world 2d object in the form of a digital image";
                word = "S C A N N E R";
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                clue = "A screen that displays output from a computer";
                word = "M O N I T O R";
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                clue = "It is a family of computer networking technologies for LANs";
                word = "E T H E R N E T";
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                clue = "It is a computer network that uses Internet Protocol technology to share information, operational systems, or computing services within an organization";
                word = "I N T R A N E T";
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                clue = "It is an IDE for Java";
                word = "B L U E J";
            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {
                clue = "It is an application developed by Microsoft that is used for playing audio, video and viewing images";
                word = "W I N D O W S | M E D I A | P L A Y E R";
            }
            break;
            case 7:
            {
                clue = "It is a software application that provides comprehensive facilities to computer programmers for software development";
                word = "I N T E G R A T E D | D E V E L O P M E N T | E N V I R O N M E N T";
            }
            break;
            case 8:
            {
                clue = "It is a temporary form of computer data storage";
                word = "R A N D O M | A C C E S S | M E M O R Y";
            }
            break;
            case 9:
            {
                clue = "It is a digital circuit that performs arithmetic and logical operations.";
                word = "A R I T H M E T I C | A N D | L O G I C | U N I T";
            }
            break;
        }
        return new String[] {word,clue};        
    }
    public String[] Food()
    {
        option = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clue = "It is an Indian food cited as top ten tasty foods of the world";
                word = "M A S A L A | D O S A";
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                clue = "A fruit which has the same name as its colour";
                word = "O R A N G E";
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                clue = "It is an oven-baked, flat, round bread typically topped with a tomato sauce, cheese and various toppings";
                word = "P I Z Z A";
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                clue = "It is a type of staple food made from some type of unleavened dough which is rolled flat and cut into long thin strips";
                word = "N O O D L E S";
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                clue = "Sorry. No clue for this one";
                word = "P I N E A P P L E";
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                clue = "A bun between which a patty is kept";
                word = "B U R G E R";
            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {
                clue = "It is a chat";
                word = "P A N I | P U R I";
            }
            break;
            case 7:
            {
                clue = "Is perfect for completing the idiom - As cool as a ______________";
                word = "C U C U M B E R";
            }
            break;
            case 8:
            {
                clue = "Consists of two or more slices of bread with fillings between them";
                word = "S A N D W I C H";
            }
            break;
            case 9:
            {
                clue = "Sorry. No clue for this one";
                word = "P A S T A";
            }
            break;
        }
        return new String[] {word,clue};        
    }
    public String[] Countries()
    {
        option = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clue = "Means 'Rich Coast' in Spanish";
                word = "C O S T A | R I C A";
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                clue = "Sorry. No clue for this one";
                word = "I N D I A";
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                clue = "T&T";
                word = "T R I N I D A D | A N D | T O B A G O";
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                clue = "Consists of nearly one thousand islands";
                word = "S O L O M O N | I S L A N D S";
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                clue = "It's capital is Riyadh";
                word = "S A U D I | A R A B I A";
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                clue = "Lucky guy : You're getting a free letter : P";
                word = "T H E | P H I L I P P I N E S";
            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {
                clue = "The fastest man on Earth is from this country";
                word = "J A M A I C A";
            }
            break;
            case 7:
            {
                clue = "3 movies have been filmed using this country's name";
                word = "M A D A G A S C A R";
            }
            break;
            case 8:
            {
                clue = "Greatest world power";
                word = "U N I T E D | S T A T E S | O F | A M E R I C A";
            }
            break;
            case 9:
            {
                clue = "Lucky guy : You're getting a free letter : Y";
                word = "M A L A Y S I A";
            }
            break;
        }
        return new String[] {word,clue};
    }
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        Hangman obj = new Hangman();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
        p.println("Lets play HANGMAN");
        p.println();
        p.println("Enter your choice according to the following options.\nNOTE: Words are related to the topics given below.\n\n1. Sports\n2. Movies\n3. Computer\n4. Food\n5. Countries");
        p.println();
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        obj.clearScreen();
        String bothwordandclue[] = new String[2];
        if(choice == 1)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Sports();
        else if(choice == 2)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Movies();
        else if(choice == 3)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Computers();
        else if(choice == 4)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Food();
        else if(choice == 5)
        bothwordandclue = obj.Countries();
        else
        p.println("Wrong choice");
        int counter = 6;
        String guessword = bothwordandclue[0];
        String wordclue = bothwordandclue[1];
        int lengthofword = (int)(Math.round(((double)guessword.length()/2)));
        int checkguess = 0;
        String a;
        String guesses[] = new String[50];
        StringBuffer guessit = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0;i<lengthofword;i++)
        guessit = guessit.append("_ ");
        guessit.delete((2 * lengthofword)-1,(2 * lengthofword));
        int index = guessword.indexOf("|");
        while(index >= 0)
        {
            guessit.setCharAt(index, '|');
            index = guessword.indexOf("|", index+1);// Start searching for next "|" after this index
        }
        p.println(guessit + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t The letters you have entered so far");
        do
        {
            p.println();
            if(counter == 6)
            obj.Hang1();
            else if(counter == 5)
            obj.Hang2();
            else if(counter == 4)
            obj.Hang3();
            else if(counter == 3)
            obj.Hang4();
            else if(counter == 2)
            obj.Hang5();
            else if(counter == 1)
            obj.Hang6();
            p.println();
            p.println("Enter your guess letter");
            String guessletter2 = br.readLine();
            String guessletter = guessletter2.toUpperCase();
            obj.clearScreen();
            for(int i = 0;i<lengthofword;i++)
            {
                if(guessletter.charAt(0) == guessword.charAt(2*i))
                {
                    guessit.setCharAt(2*i,guessletter.charAt(0));
                    checkguess=1;
                }                
            }
            if(checkguess == 1)
            {
                p.println("Correct Guess. You have " + counter + " incorrect guesses left\t\t\t\t\t\t\t The letters you have entered so far");
                p.println(guessit);
            }
            else
            {
                counter--;
                if(counter == 0)
                {
                    p.println("Wrong guess. You hanged the man :(");
                    p.println(guessit);
                    obj.Hang7();
                }
                else
                {
                    p.println("Wrong guess. You have " + counter + " incorrect guesses left\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t The letters you have entered so far");
                    p.println(guessit);
                }
            }
            checkguess = 0;
            if(counter == 0)
            p.println("\nSorry you lost the game\n\nThe correct word is " + guessword);
            a = guessit.toString();
            if(a.equals(guessword))
            {
                p.println("You guessed the word!!!!!");
                counter=0;
            }        
        }while(counter>0);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i just had a mini-heart attack.

Comment: @RussellGutierrez. How're you feeling now?

Comment: @RohitJain recovering, thank you.

Comment: @RussellGutierrez. Hope to see you in action soon. :)

Comment: More loops and arrays, more conditionals. Less repeated code blocks (you can make the hangman draw one section) and no break statements!!!

Comment: So how are you trying to do it and how isn't the outcome what you expected?

Comment: hey guys im still a beginner and i am limited to only a few options and cannot use complex stuff

Comment: i want to display the users guesses. Just check the main method and dont worry about the rest

Comment: @RohitJain Please check the main method

Comment: @RussellGutierrez Please check the main method

Comment: @crvineeth99. It would be better to tell exactly what problem are you facing, rather than saying check the main method. It is equivalent to saying check my complete program.

Comment: @crvineeth99. In fact I appreciate your work, if you are just a beginner. Writing that clear code, though not enough to understand it because it's so long, for a beginner, is really nice to see.

Comment: Guys, guys, guys! We all start somewhere, the questioners profile says he is 15 years old

Comment: @RohitJain I could have made it much simpler using Double Dimensional Arrays but we shouldnt use it so bear with me and sorry for asking you to check the whole main method.

Comment: @DaveRlz. Yeah that's why I said, I appreciate his work. I couldn't even imagine how my initial codes that I wrote when I started coding, look like. Of course far behind the quality of this one. :)

Comment: @crvineeth99. It's ok. I shouldn't have said it like that. Let me check your code.

Comment: @crvineeth99. Your code is working pretty fine. Just correct the signature of your main method to : -`public static void main(String args[])`. And also, your `clearScreen()` method is printing some odd characters. You can comment out the `sysout` in that method.

Comment: @RohitJain I am using a user friendly application called BlueJ which does not need command line arguments like String args[] or String orgs[] and also we can clear the screen at method call :P

Comment: @crvineeth99. You cannot change the signature of the main method, whatever environment you are using. That is the pre-defined method signature. If you alter it, it is no more a main method.

Comment: @RohitJain OK I get your point but why don't you try it out. Download BlueJ from here http://www.bluej.org/download/download.html. It still shows it as main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main() is missing the String array args, it should be :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
```

add that in and it will run.

Also, you are not storing your guess letter and not printing it out, so it's not being displayed. To fix this, change your guesses String array to a simple String and just after you do uppercase on guessletter add this line:

```
guesses += guessletter;
```

then after each println() that says 'The letters you have entered so far' print out the guesses String. This will then display the list of guessed letters.

We all start somewhere, your code reminds me of the first stuff I wrote 30 years ago. Once it is all working take a look at your code and figure out what can be improved.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I can improve it and make it smaller but i am not supposed to

Answer (score 1):

You just can make a string `madeGuesses="";` and keep adding the characters in to it, then print it out afterwards, e.g.

```
System.out.print(\u000method  clearScreen method Email..e for more
```

Comment: this post looks like it might have been inadvertently truncated somehow - could you flesh out on the lines of code at the end? Thanks